# How to backup a wordpress.com blog

Tags: wordpress, wordpress.com

I have one blog on wordpress.com ,how to crate back up of blog ,there is no add plugin option ,how can i back up all files and data base.any way take back up blog. 
I am trying from last 2 hours Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a  backup of the DataBase. But you can export all the data to a XML file.
Check [Export](http://en.support.wordpress.com/export/)

You can import this XML file into any fresh installation of WordPress.

Comment: and what about all other flies of wordpress ,its possible or not ?

Comment: If by files you mean the images/videos you uploaded, those will be automatically imported to the new blog via the XML. The XML has a path to those media files. 

But If you mean the Theme files and the code files, I do not think that is possible.

Comment: In that case, just set up wordpress on the other host, and just import the XML file there. That should work.